# describe composite type wsdl

Tags: web-services, qt, xsd, wsdl

I get this method implement on qt.

```
QList<Job> getJobs(unsigned int firtJob, unsigned int lastJob);
```

And I would like to use with a web service but i don`t but I do not define it in the file .wsdl.

```
<message name="getJobsRequest">
  <part name="firtJob" type="xsd:unsigedInt" />
  <part name="lastJob" type="xsd:unsigedInt" />
</message>
<message name="getJobsResponse">
 .....
</message>

<portType name="CorePortType">
  <operation name="getJobs">
    <input message="tns:getJobsRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:getJobsResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
```

I do not know how to describe getJobsResponse I guess it will be a composite type

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i solved this problem with:

```
<complexType>
   <all>
     <sequence>
       <element name="list_job" type="Job" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     <sequence>
   </all>
</complexType>

<message name="getJobsResponse">
   <part name="listJobs" type="tns:list_job" />
</message>
```

Thanks